# An Article on an Application of Fractional Calculus

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fractional-calculus

Just need some clarification on a few things from this article that I am reading: *Solutions of the Telegraph Equations using a Fractional Calculus Approach.*

[This article goes briefly over the fractional differential equation for the Telegrapher's Equation (Transmission line equation) without losses in terms of
the fractional time derivatives](http://www.acad.ro/sectii2002/proceedings/doc2014-1/04-Baleanu.pdf)

> Quick note - since it isn't directly mentioned in the article - for those of you are wondering what the Telegrapher's Equation with loss:
>   \begin{eqnarray}
> \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2} & = & RGV + (LG+RC)\frac{\partial V}{\partial t} + LC \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial t^2}
> \end{eqnarray}
>   and without losses (implying conductance $G$ and resistance $R$ are zero): 
>   \begin{eqnarray}
> \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2} & = & LC \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial t^2}
> \end{eqnarray}
>   Where $V=V(x,t)$ is our voltage across the transmission line.

The first case they talk about is the Fractional Time case, where our fractional time derivative is 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2} - \frac{LC}{(\sigma_t)^{2(1-\gamma)}} \frac{\partial^{2\gamma} V}{\partial t^{2\gamma}} & = & 0
\end{eqnarray}
Where , $0 < \gamma \leq 1$.

I have many questions regarding their results and how they define certain things. For starters, they define $\sigma_t$ as a new parameter representing the fractional time component; however, I am not sure what exactly it is. Same goes for the spatial case when they define $\alpha_x$ as a new parameter for the fractional space.

I was curious as to how they knew the following particular solution to the Fractional Time Transmission line equation: 
\begin{eqnarray}
V(x,t) = V_0e^{-ikx}u(t)
\end{eqnarray}

Afterwards, they combine the result and the Fractional-Time Derivative to get $u(t)$ (which I also wonder how they got it). 
\begin{eqnarray}
u(t) = E_{2\gamma}\{-\omega^2t^{2\gamma}\}
\end{eqnarray}

As a result, the particular solution they obtained was

\begin{eqnarray}
V(x,t) = V_0e^{-ikx}E_{2\gamma}\{-\omega^2t^{2\gamma}\}
\end{eqnarray}

> Note $E_{2\gamma}(t)$ is the Mittag-Leffler function defined by 
>   \begin{eqnarray}
> E_{2\gamma}(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{\Gamma(2\gamma + 1)}
> \end{eqnarray}

I have similar questions for the Fractional-Spatial case, but I will focus on that later once I fully understood the Fractional-Time case.

---

I'm trying to understand this article to the best of my abilities for a brief report I am writing for my Fractional Calculus course. Hopefully I can. I do want to add I am fairly new to fractional calculus myself, this being my first semester.

---

I'm sorry for the long read but I thank you so much for taking the time to help me further my knowledge in fractional calculus (mathematics in general). I greatly appreciate any guidance you may give me. Thank you once again.

Comment: @ Kevin_H : I do not pretend to give guidance on this particular application of fractionnal calculus. May be you would be interrested on a more general view, such as shown in the papers : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14686539/The-Fractional-Derivation-La-derivation-fractionnaire , https://fr.scribd.com/doc/71923015/The-Phasance-Concept .

Comment: To explain where $\sigma$ and $\alpha$ come from, they are simply defining new things that follow from the following true statement: $$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}=\frac{d^{n+k}}{dx^{n+k}}$$For the other results, they may have more equations they expect the audience to know, and they are probably solving differential equations.